# Django: Where can i find user login, logout activity for past 1 year

Tags: django

In django, is there any where the login, and logout activity for past 1 year

is there any tables which stores these details

I am using a web, session based application

Comment: Django does not store this. It makes use of `Session`s that encode a reference to the user, but these sessions are regularly removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any tables which stores these details.

**No**. Django will, by default store session data with a [**`Session`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.base_session.AbstractBaseSession), but that session does not contain a reference to the user: it uses a `session_key` which is used by the browser of that user. But a session thus does *not* directly maps on a user. Furthermore a session does not contain any information when the user has logged in or logged out, it only has an `expire_date`.

You can however design a model yourself to keep track of user activity:

```
from django.conf import settings

class UserActivity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_index=True)
    login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    logout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
```

This might be one of the rare cases to use signals:

```
from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_in, user_logged_out
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from django.db.models.functions import Now

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def register_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    UserActivity.objects.create(
        user=user,
        session_key=request.session.session_key
    )

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def register_logout(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    UserActivity.objects.filter(
        user=user,
        session_key=request.session.session_key
    ).update(
        logout=Now()
    )
```

Note that if a session expires this will not trigger the `user_logged_out` view, so likely a lot of `UserActivity`s will have a value for `login`, but not for `logout`.